# How to create a form for feeding multiple object entries based on a query in django?

Tags: html, django

I am currently working on my college management application, where `staff` can enter internal marks of students and the student can view their marks. What i am stuck with is, i want a populate a list of forms to fill the internal marks of each student and submit it at once.

I tried modelformset with the code below and it work exactly as below

```py
formset = modelformset_factory(Internal, fields=('student','marks1','marks2','marks3'))
        if request.method == "POST":
            form=formset(request.POST)
            form.save()
        form = formset()
        return render(request, 'console/academics/internals.html',{'form':form})
```

For the model

```py
class Internal(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    marks1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    marks2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    marks3 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    marks = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    marksob = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self):
        self.marksob = (self.marks1 + self.marks2 + self.marks3)/15
        return super(Internal, self).save()
```

I want the form to be rendered in html using `<input>` and not passing `{{form}}` in html. And moreover I want the form to display only the entries of particular students based on a query. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the form to display only the entries of particular students based on a query.

As stated in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset), you can specify a `queryset` for your formset:

```
formset = modelformset_factory(Internal, queryset=Internal.Objects.filter(...), fields=('student','marks1','marks2','marks3'))
```

> I want the form to be rendered in html using  and not passing {{form}} in html

You can do that by iterating over fields, just like normal forms:

```
<form method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {% for field in form %}
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

More details at [using the formset in the template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-the-formset-in-the-template).

#### Edit

If you want to use custom css classes for your form fields, you can do:

```
<form method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}

        <div class="...">
            {{ form.marks1.errors }}
            <label for="{{ form.marks1.id_for_label }}">Your email address:</label>
            <input type="number" name="{{ form.marks1.name }}" value="{{ form.marks1.value }}" class="css-class">
        </div>

        <!-- and for other fields as well -->

    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Comment: That worked!! But is there a way to style the field with CSS properties?

Comment: @Mowli Yes, you can render _each_ field **manually** and add classes in the html element; for example: `<input type='number' class='my-custom-class' ...>`. Check [rendering fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)

Comment: But that doesn't allow to style the `{{field}}`. It is just the wrapping the label along with the `{{field}}` right? If I am wrong, then please update your answer with any bootstrap field class! That will be a really big help

Comment: It worked perfectly with all fields except the `student` and `subject` field. Should i make some changes?

Comment: For sure, you should use `type="text"` for subject and also a custom `<select>` element for `student`.

Comment: Also consider using [django-widget-tweaks](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks) if that's what you want.

Comment: Can't I just populate the name of the student alone. Imagine list of students name with 3 field for marks and 1 common field for subject!

Comment: If you want to use a **common** field for the subject (that is, you enter the 3 marks for each student, but all having a common subject), you should remove the `subject` field from your `formset` and pass the `subject` as a single, separate value; then, before saving the `formset`, apply the subject to that.

Comment: From everything you said, would you recommend method 1(ie `{{field}}`) with widget tweaks or method 2 using html `<input>` rendering?

Comment: I prefer using `widget-tweaks` because it will reduce the overhead of adding extra code for proper error handling, help text and label.